# Akonadi: How to deactivate push-IMAP (IMAP IDLE connections)

Tags: email, imap, kmail, akonadi

I have an IMAP email account (the provider doesn't offer POP3 anymore). In Kmail, new mails now appear instantly. But I prefer to retrieve mails from the provider in manual mail checks only. This way, I see in which folders new mail has arrived ... otherwise, I don't know because I always have a few unread emails in different folders which are just waiting for my attention (and would look the same as newly received IMAP-push mails).

So, is there a way to deactivate IMAP-push in Akonadi such that I can determine when to check for new mail on the server?

many thanks in advance, Angela

Answer (score 2):

There is an option to check mail periodically rather than using IMAP idle.
Settings -> Configure KMail -> Accounts -> Click on your account -> "Enable interval mail checking"